# Using data from one view function in another with Django (forms)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently using Django to have users enter data using a form. Using my views.py file, I was able to write a views function that stores the data users enter. However. What I want to do, is take the data the users has enter and use it in another views function in my "views.py" file.

For example, here is my views.py file:

```
def s(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)

        if search.is_valid():
            success = True
            name = search.cleaned_data['search']
        else:
            print search.errors

    else:
        search = Search()

    return HttpResponse(name)
```

What I'd then like to do is create a second view function and be able to call the "name" variable defined above. Anyone know how I could go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do in the second view. Try passing parameters.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def s(request):
    search = Search()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)
        if search.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/second-url/?name=%s' %(search.cleaned_data['search'],))
    return render(request, 'template_name', {'form': search})

def s2(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    return HttpResponse('hello %s' % name)
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I want to be able to call the variable, 'name' in other functions in my views. Sort of [like this](http://pastebin.com/LvuXAAXb)

Comment: Search is a from I imported from my ['forms.py' file](http://pastebin.com/LUMrGkRW).

Comment: Dumb question.. didn't saw you were calling .is_valid there. Check the updated answer.